# Cleaner way to define multiple nested elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a div with an id of slide. Within there are other divs with classes ranging from bcg2 to bcg9. I need all the nested elements to apply the below properties. I cannot blanket apply this to nested elements as there are other elements such as text and images inside the parent div.

```
#slide .bcg2, #slide .bcg3, #slide .bcg4, #slide .bcg5, #slide .bcg6, #slide .bcg7, #slide .bcg8, #slide .bcg9 {bottom:0; left: 50%; margin-left:-600px;}
```

Is there a neater way to define this without redefining #slide every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they only have the class of `.bcgNUMBER`, you could try:

```
#slide [class^="bcg"] {}
```

Otherwise, there's no way in pure CSS.

Using [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/), you could do:

```
#slide {
    .bcg2, .bcg3, .bcg4, .bcg5, .bcg6, .bcg7, .bcg8, .bcg9 {}
}
```

And it will compile into what you had.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different styles in one element.

```
.parent{bottom:0; left: 50%; margin-left:-600px;}
```

then you just add this class in html with a space, for example:

```
<div class="parent anotherstyle"></div>
```